# Country calling code uniquely keyed by code array in Japanese, ruby, yml, php

Tags: arrays, phone-number, country-codes, cjk, keyedcollection

Asking this question to answer it myself as it's a useful resource for others.

I got this by filtering out the information on the Japanese country codes wiki article
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7

I took out some of the information you typically wouldn't want in an array for any sort of development. (I'll post that too)

I will provide in yaml/yml format for now.

Comment: *Asking this question ...*  What question ?

Comment: Sorry, just meant to provide a useful resource for others. Will mark it as answered when I can.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

[code]: +[code] [where/what it is used for]

```
1: +1 アメリカ合衆国、カナダ
1242: +1242 バハマ
1246: +1246 バルバドス
1264: +1264 アングィラ
1268: +1268 アンティグア・バーブーダ
1284: +1284 英領ヴァージン諸島
1340: +1340 米領ヴァージン諸島
1345: +1345 英領ケイマン諸島
1441: +1441 バミューダ諸島
1473: +1473 グレナダ
1649: +1649 タークス及びカイコス諸島
1664: +1664 モントセラト
1721: +1721 オランダ領セント・マーチン
1758: +1758 セントルシア
1767: +1767 ドミニカ国
1784: +1784 セントビンセントおよびグレナディーン諸島
1787: +1787 プエルトリコ
1809: +1809 ドミニカ共和国
1829: +1829 ドミニカ共和国
1849: +1849 ドミニカ共和国
1868: +1868 トリニダード・トバゴ
1869: +1869 セントキッツ・ネイビス
1876: +1876 ジャマイカ
1939: +1939 プエルトリコ
1670: +1670 北マリアナ諸島
1671: +1671 グアム
1684: +1684 アメリカ領サモア
1808: +1808 ハワイ諸島、ミッドウェー諸島
20: +20 エジプト
211: +211 南スーダン
212: +212 モロッコ
213: +213 アルジェリア
216: +216 チュニジア
218: +218 リビア
220: +220 ガンビア
221: +221 セネガル
222: +222 モーリタニア
223: +223 マリ
224: +224 ギニア
225: +225 コートジボワール
226: +226 ブルキナファソ
227: +227 ニジェール
228: +228 トーゴ
229: +229 ベナン
230: +230 モーリシャス
231: +231 リベリア
232: +232 シエラレオネ
233: +233 ガーナ
234: +234 ナイジェリア
235: +235 チャド
236: +236 中央アフリカ共和国
237: +237 カメルーン
238: +238 カーボベルデ
239: +239 サントメ・プリンシペ
240: +240 赤道ギニア
241: +241 ガボン
242: +242 コンゴ共和国
243: +243 コンゴ民主共和国
244: +244 アンゴラ
245: +245 ギニアビサウ
246: +246 ディエゴガルシア島
247: +247 アセンション島
248: +248 セーシェル
249: +249 スーダン
250: +250 ルワンダ
251: +251 エチオピア
252: +252 ソマリア
253: +253 ジブチ
254: +254 ケニア
255: +255 タンザニア
256: +256 ウガンダ
257: +257 ブルンジ
258: +258 モザンビーク
260: +260 ザンビア
261: +261 マダガスカル
262: +262 レユニオン、マヨット
263: +263 ジンバブエ
264: +264 ナミビア
265: +265 マラウイ
266: +266 レソト
267: +267 ボツワナ
268: +268 スワジランド
269: +269 コモロ
27: +27 南アフリカ共和国
282: +282 西サハラ
2897: +2897 トリスタンダクーニャ
290: +290 セントヘレナ島
291: +291 エリトリア
297: +297 アルバ
298: +298 フェロー諸島
299: +299 グリーンランド
30: +30 ギリシャ
31: +31 オランダ
32: +32 ベルギー
33: +33 フランス
34: +34 スペイン
350: +350 ジブラルタル
351: +351 ポルトガル
352: +352 ルクセンブルク
353: +353 アイルランド
354: +354 アイスランド
355: +355 アルバニア
356: +356 マルタ
357: +357 キプロス
358: +358 フィンランド
359: +359 ブルガリア
36: +36 ハンガリー
370: +370 リトアニア
371: +371 ラトビア
372: +372 エストニア
373: +373 モルドバ
374: +374 アルメニア
375: +375 ベラルーシ
376: +376 アンドラ
377: +377 モナコ
378: +378 サンマリノ
379: +379 バチカン
380: +380 ウクライナ
381: +381 セルビア
382: +382 モンテネグロ
383: +383 コソボ
385: +385 クロアチア
386: +386 スロベニア
387: +387 ボスニア・ヘルツェゴビナ
388: +388 ETNS
389: +389 マケドニア
39: +39 イタリア
40: +40 ルーマニア
41: +41 スイス
420: +420 チェコ
421: +421 スロバキア
423: +423 リヒテンシュタイン
43: +43 オーストリア
44: +44 イギリス
45: +45 デンマーク
46: +46 スウェーデン
47: +47 ノルウェー
48: +48 ポーランド
49: +49 ドイツ
500: +500 フォークランド諸島
501: +501 ベリーズ
502: +502 グアテマラ
503: +503 エルサルバドル
504: +504 ホンジュラス
505: +505 ニカラグア
506: +506 コスタリカ
507: +507 パナマ
508: +508 フランス領サンピエール・ミクロン
509: +509 ハイチ
51: +51 ペルー
52: +52 メキシコ
53: +53 キューバ
54: +54 アルゼンチン
55: +55 ブラジル
56: +56 チリ
57: +57 コロンビア
58: +58 ベネズエラ
590: +590 フランス領セントマーチン
591: +591 ボリビア
592: +592 ガイアナ
593: +593 エクアドル
594: +594 フランス領ギアナ
595: +595 パラグアイ
596: +596 フランス領マルチニーク島
597: +597 スリナム
598: +598 ウルグアイ
599: +599 オランダ領アンティル諸島
60: +60 マレーシア
61: +61 オーストラリア、 クリスマス島、ココス諸島
62: +62 インドネシア
63: +63 フィリピン
64: +64 ニュージーランド
65: +65 シンガポール
66: +66 タイ
670: +670 東ティモール
672: +672 ノーフォーク島、南極大陸
673: +673 ブルネイ
674: +674 ナウル
675: +675 パプアニューギニア
676: +676 トンガ
677: +677 ソロモン諸島
678: +678 バヌアツ
679: +679 フィジー
680: +680 パラオ
681: +681 ウォリス・フツナ
682: +682 クック諸島
683: +683 ニウエ
685: +685 サモア
686: +686 キリバス
687: +687 ニューカレドニア
688: +688 ツバル
689: +689 フランス領ポリネシア
690: +690 トケラウ諸島
691: +691 ミクロネシア連邦
692: +692 マーシャル諸島
7: +7 ロシア、カザフスタン
800: +800 国際フリーフォン
808: +808 国際分担課金
81: +81 日本
82: +82 大韓民国
84: +84 ベトナム
850: +850 朝鮮民主主義人民共和国
852: +852 香港
853: +853 マカオ
855: +855 カンボジア
856: +856 ラオス
86: +86 中華人民共和国
870: +870 インマルサット
871: +871 インマルサット - 大西洋東 → 「870」に統合
872: +872 インマルサット - 太平洋 → 「870」に統合
873: +873 インマルサット - インド洋 → 「870」に統合
874: +874 インマルサット - 大西洋西 → 「870」に統合
878: +878 国際パーソナル通信サービス (UPT)
880: +880 バングラデシュ
8812: +8812 ellipso
8813: +8813 ellipso
8816: +8816 イリジウム
8817: +8817 イリジウム
8818: +8818 グローバルスター
8819: +8819 グローバルスター
88210: +88210 BT
88211: +88211 シンガポール・テレコム
88212: +88212 ベライゾン・コミュニケーションズ
88213: +88213 テレスパツィオ　
88214: +88214 旧GTE　
88215: +88215 テルストラ　
88216: +88216 スラーヤ
88217: +88217 旧AT&T国際ATMネットワーク
88218: +88218 旧テレデシック
88219: +88219 旧テレコム・イタリア
88220: +88220 ACeS
88221: +88221 旧アメリテック
88222: +88222 ケーブル・アンド・ワイヤレス
88223: +88223 SITAとイクアントの協業
88224: +88224 テリア
88225: +88225 旧Constallation Communications
88226: +88226 旧SBCコミュニケーションズ
88227: +88227 旧ウィリアムズコミュニケーションズ
88228: +88228 ドイツテレコム
88229: +88229 旧Q-TEL
88230: +88230 Optus
88231: +88231 テレコム・マレーシア
88232: +88232 Maritime Communications Partner
88233: +88233 Oration Technologies
88234: +88234 Global Networks Inc.
88235: +88235 ジャスパーワイヤレス
88236: +88236 ジャージーテレコム
88237: +88237 AT&Tモビリティ
88238: +88238 ellipso
88239: +88239 Vodafone Malta
88240: +88240 Cubio
88241: +88241 Intermatica
88242: +88242 Seanet Maritime Communications AB
88243: +88243 Ukrainian Radiosystems for Beeline
88245: +88245 テレコム・イタリア
88246: +88246 tyntec
88297: +88297 Smart Communications
88298: +88298 ONAIR N.V.
88299: +88299 Telenor
883: +883 国際ネットワーク
886: +886 台湾
888: +888 災害・救済のための情報通信のために割り当て
90: +90 トルコ
91: +91 インド
92: +92 パキスタン
93: +93 アフガニスタン
94: +94 スリランカ
95: +95 ミャンマー
960: +960 モルジブ
961: +961 レバノン
962: +962 ヨルダン
963: +963 シリア
964: +964 イラク
965: +965 クウェート
966: +966 サウジアラビア
967: +967 イエメン
968: +968 オマーン
971: +971 アラブ首長国連邦
972: +972 イスラエル
973: +973 バーレーン
974: +974 カタール
975: +975 ブータン
976: +976 モンゴル
977: +977 ネパール
98: +98 イラン
991: +991 国際電話公衆通信サービス (ITPCS)
992: +992 タジキスタン
993: +993 トルクメニスタン
994: +994 アゼルバイジャン
995: +995 ジョージア
996: +996 キルギスタン
998: +998 ウズベキスタン
```

The wiki originally had some more information. The following information was removed as it is not pertinent to most projects:

```
Deleted: 881x   GMSS - グローバルな衛星移動通信システム
Deleted: 882xx  国際ネットワーク



Deleted:
259: 未使用（かつてザンジバルに割り当てられていた。現在はタンザニアに統合され255）
Deleted:
280: 未割り当て
Deleted:
281: 未割り当て
Deleted:
283: 未割り当て
Deleted:
284: 未割り当て
Deleted:
285: 未割り当て
Deleted:
286: 未割り当て
Deleted:
287: 未割り当て
Deleted:
288: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2890: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2891: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2892: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2893: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2894: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2895: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2896: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2898: 未割り当て
Deleted:
2899: 未割り当て
Deleted:
292: 未割り当て
Deleted:
293: 未割り当て
Deleted:
294: 未割り当て
Deleted:
295: 未割り当て
Deleted:
296: 未割り当て
Deleted:
384: 未使用
Deleted:
422: 未使用
Deleted:
424: 未使用
Deleted:
425: 未使用
Deleted:
426: 未使用
Deleted:
427: 未使用
Deleted:
428: 未使用
Deleted:
429: 未使用
Deleted:
671: 未使用（かつてグアム島で使っていた番号。現在は「1671」に変更）
Deleted:
684: 未使用（かつてアメリカ領サモアが使っていた番号。現在は「1684」に変更）
Deleted:
693: 未使用
Deleted:
694: 未使用
Deleted:
695: 未使用
Deleted:
696: 未使用
Deleted:
697: 未使用
Deleted:
698: 未使用
Deleted:
699: 未使用
Deleted:
801: 未使用
Deleted:
802: 未使用
Deleted:
803: 未使用
Deleted:
804: 未使用
Deleted:
805: 未使用
Deleted:
806: 未使用
Deleted:
807: 未使用
Deleted:
809: 未使用
Deleted:
83: 未使用
Deleted:
851: 未使用
Deleted:
854: 未使用
Deleted:
857: 未使用
Deleted:
858: 未使用
Deleted:
859: 未使用
Deleted:
8814: 未使用
Deleted:
8815: 未使用
Deleted:
884: 未使用
Deleted:
885: 未使用
Deleted:
887: 未使用
Deleted:
889: 未使用
Deleted:
89: 未使用
Deleted:
969: 未使用（かつて、南イエメンが使用していた。現在は967）
Deleted:
978: 未使用（かつて、ドバイに割り当てられていた。現在は971）
Deleted:
990: 未使用
Deleted:
997: 未使用



Deleted:
210: モロッコによる予約
Deleted:
214: アルジェリアによる予約
Deleted:
215: アルジェリアによる予約
Deleted:
217: チュニジアによる予約
Deleted:
219: リビアによる予約
Deleted:
875: Maritime Mobile serviceによる予約
Deleted:
876: Maritime Mobile serviceによる予約
Deleted:
877: Maritime Mobile serviceによる予約
Deleted:
879: national mobile/maritime 使用による予約
Deleted:
8810: ICOグローバルによる予約
Deleted:
8811: ICOグローバルによる予約
Deleted:
970: パレスチナ自治政府の予約。
Deleted:
999: 災害救助サービスのための予約



Deleted:
979: 国際プレミアムレート（かつて、アブダビに割り当てられていた。現在は971）



previous: 262   レユニオン、マヨット  共にフランス領
Removed: 共にフランス領

previous: アメリカ合衆国、カナダ [2]
removed: [2]







previous:
+878 国際パーソナル通信サービス (UPT - Universal Personal Telecommunications services): 878
removed:
- Universal Personal Telecommunications services



previous:
+800 国際フリーフォン（着信課金電話番号。国境を越えるフリーダイヤル相当）: 800
Removed:
（着信課金電話番号。国境を越えるフリーダイヤル相当）

previous:
+808 国際分担課金（シェアド・コスト）: 808
Removed:
（シェアド・コスト）

previous:
+88213 テレスパツィオ　（イタリアの衛星通信事業者）: 88213
Removed:
（イタリアの衛星通信事業者）

previous:
+88214 旧GTE　（ベライゾン・コミュニケーションズの子会社）: 88214
Removed:
（ベライゾン・コミュニケーションズの子会社）

previous:
+88215 テルストラ　（オーストラリアの衛星通信事業者）: 88215
Removed:
（オーストラリアの衛星通信事業者）

previous:
+88216 スラーヤ（アラブ首長国連邦が提供している衛星電話サービス）: 88216
Removed:
（アラブ首長国連邦が提供している衛星電話サービス）

previous:
+88220 ACeS（東南アジアを中心とした地域向けの衛星電話サービス。端末は無線局免許の関係で日本国内では使用できない）: 88220
Removed:
（東南アジアを中心とした地域向けの衛星電話サービス。端末は無線局免許の関係で日本国内では使用できない）

previous:
+88221 旧アメリテック（AT&Tの子会社）: 88221
Removed:
（AT&Tの子会社）

previous:
+88223 SITAとイクアント（Orangeの子会社）の協業:
Removed:
（Orangeの子会社）

previous:
+88225 旧Constallation Communications（アメリカ合衆国の通信事業者）: 88225
Removed:
（アメリカ合衆国の通信事業者）

previous:
+88226 旧SBCコミュニケーションズ（現・AT&T）: 88226
Removed:
（現・AT&T）

previous:
+88229 旧Q-TEL（ニュージーランドの通信事業者）: 88229
Removed:
（ニュージーランドの通信事業者）

previous:
+88230 Optus（オーストラリアの通信事業者）: 88230
Removed:
（オーストラリアの通信事業者）

previous:
+88232 Maritime Communications Partner（ノルウェーの海上衛星通信事業者）: 88232
Removed:
（ノルウェーの海上衛星通信事業者）

previous:
+88233 Oration Technologies（イギリスの通信事業者）: 88233
Removed:
（イギリスの通信事業者）

previous:
+88234 Global Networks Inc.（スイスの通信事業者）: 88234
Removed:
（スイスの通信事業者）

previous:
+88235 ジャスパーワイヤレス（アメリカ合衆国の海上衛星通信事業者）: 88235
Removed:
（アメリカ合衆国の海上衛星通信事業者）

previous:
+88236 ジャージーテレコム（イギリスの通信事業者）: 88236
Removed:
（イギリスの通信事業者）

previous:
+88239 Vodafone Malta（ボーダフォンのマルタ国内の現地法人）: 88239
Removed:
（ボーダフォンのマルタ国内の現地法人）

previous:
+88240 Cubio（フィンランドの通信事業者）: 88240
Removed:
（フィンランドの通信事業者）

previous:
+88241 Intermatica（イタリアの通信事業者）: 88241
Removed:
（イタリアの通信事業者）

previous:
+88242 Seanet Maritime Communications AB（スウェーデンの海上通信事業者）: 88242
Removed:
（スウェーデンの海上通信事業者）

previous:
+88243 Ukrainian Radiosystems for Beeline（ウクライナ共和国の通信事業者）: 88243
Removed:
（ウクライナ共和国の通信事業者）

previous:
+88246 tyntec（ドイツ法人）: 88246
Removed:
（ドイツ法人）

previous:
+88297 Smart Communications（フィリピンの長距離電話会社PLDTの子会社）: 88297
Removed:
（フィリピンの長距離電話会社PLDTの子会社）

previous:
+88298 ONAIR N.V.（SITAによる航空機内におけるGSMサービス）: 88298
Removed:
（SITAによる航空機内におけるGSMサービス）
```